# CentOS 6.5 compiling kernel source seeing "LINUX_VERSION_CODE" unset

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I followed following instructions to install the kernel source code onto my CentOS 6.5 development box(from http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source)

[user@host]$ cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
[user@host SPECS]$ rpmbuild -bp --target=$(uname -m) kernel.spec

Overall, I now have the source under ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6/linux-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64/

However, when I try to compile netmap (which applies patches to the kernel source directory). I notice the following warnings

ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/linux/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

I am not seeing this on Ubuntu. I'm suspecting that I did not prepare the kernel source tree correctly, can I do that with Redhat kernel source RPM?

Answer (score 0):

Ran, "make oldconfig", "make preprare", and "make prepare scripts" prior to building against kernel source